# Correct way to grant Bigquery Client Tools access for user for table backed by sheets, but API still fails

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

In our organisation we have a standard user who created all the Bigquery projects, tables, and some Google Sheets that they point to.

We created another user in the organisation, granted them `Bigquery Data Viewer` and `Bigquery Data User` permissions, and allowed them access to the Google Sheet. They are able to access the standard tables, but the not the ones backed by Google Sheets; they get the error `Encountered an error while globbing file pattern.`

Granting that new user `Bigquery Editor` permission, they can create their own tables backed by sheets, but they get this dialog box:

[image: Bigquery Client Tools Would like to Allow]

After granting permissions, we can remove the `Bigquery Editor` permission and the user continues to have access to the all the existing Bigquery tables including those backed by sheets.

Looking in the new user's Google Account https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions, we see they've added the Bigquery Client Tools:

[image: Google Account shows Bigquery Client Tools]

**Question 1:** What is the correct way to grant this permission for new users? We've found two work-arounds:

- Grab the URL from the pop-up and edit it for new users, without the need to grant them Editor permission.
- Get the users to save a query out to Google Sheets, which triggers the pop-up.

But we've found no programatic way to grant the users this permission.

**Further...**

However, the API still seems to have problems. We ran:

```
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
# approve permissions in the web browser for the new user
bq query --apilog=apil.log "SELECT * FROM [warehouse:catalog.table]"
```

and our log shows either `"An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."` or `"Encountered an error while globbing file pattern."`; for example:

```
INFO:root:{
 [...]
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": [...]
  "jobId": "bqjob_r2410ded84270edc0_00000158fdea47bb_1"
 },
 "status": {
  "state": "DONE",
  "errorResult": {
   "reason": "internalError",
   "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."
  },
  "errors": [
   {
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."
   }
  ]
 },
 [...]
}
```

**Question 2:** What further do we need to do to grant data access through the API/cli?

Comment: Have you done of 3 of these steps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731823/encountered-an-error-while-globbing-file-pattern-error-when-using-bigquery-api

Comment: Yes, we've run those steps for the second question; and they had no effect :-( The error perhaps indicates it's an internal error, rather than a permissions problem.

Comment: Odd. Maybe one of the Google engineers can have a look at the error internally using the job id.

Comment: Could you confirm you've added the service account as an editor on the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have a separate dataset with views querying the original dataset. You can [share dataset with views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views). Which means that views will have access to a dataset and then you can give the users access to the "view dataset".

Dataset_A (google sheets)

- shared with views in the Dataset_views

Dataset_views

- shared with the users (or group)