# How to share a BigQuery table whose datasource is Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I made a BigQuery table backed by Google spreadsheet and it worked great until I shared it with some project members.
All the project members have permission to access all the resources in the BigQuery project and the Google spreadsheet, but the only person who can execute SQL on the table backed by a Google spreadsheet is the one who made the table.

When other people run queries, they get the error message below.

> Error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern.

Is it specification (or restriction) of BigQuery? Or is there any configuration that I should activate when I share such a table with others?

Comment: How are the _"others"_ running their queries - through the web UI, or programmatically through an SDK like Python, Java etc.?

Comment: Also, did you share the dataset where the table lives via email, or are the _"others"_ added at the IAM level e.g. project viewers or BigQuery users etc.?

Comment: One of the steps you have to do is grant their user's Bigquery tools Google Drive access. I don't know the way to do this properly, but see up first question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146870/correct-way-to-grant-bigquery-client-tools-access-for-user-for-table-backed-by-s