# Spring Cloud GCP: using default credentials provider but with customised scopes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I'd like my app to use the default application credential chain but to be able to customise the access scopes available to the role. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Spring Cloud GCP provides an option to set scopes for the credentials. To do that you need to specify, eg: `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.scopes=DEFAULT_SCOPES,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision` in your application.ini/yaml file or as per usual in Spring you can use environmental variables to do it as well, eg: `export SPRING_CLOUD_GCP_CREDENTIALS_SCOPES=DEFAULT_SCOPES,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

For more details check:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/#scopes

Comment: Note that scopes limit the permissions IAM roles provide. You cannot increase permissions via scopes. There are details that require knowing the service being called. Google services and Google Cloud services are managed differently regarding OAuth Scopes.

Comment: This is not what I observed. Without additional scope I wasn't able to perform an operation and with additional scope I was able to perform it. I'm coming from AWS background and find GCP IAM model confusing. If you know good in-depth materials I would appreciate it ... The default docs are not great in that regard

Comment: Unless ... additional scope was adding capability of top what DEFAULT_SCOPES permit. DEFAULT_SCOPES could have been limiting what IAM role was able to do before my change. But DEFAULT_SCOPES are there by default and I didn't see an option to authenticate without any scopes

Comment: I also have an extensive AWS background. The two authorization methods are very different. The key with Google Cloud is to understand OAUTH/OIDC. The key scope is **cloud-platform** which does not **restrict** anything that the IAM role grants. From there control permissions via IAM Roles. Scopes are a legacy (before IAM) permission mechanism. Also important to understand is that there are Google services and Google Cloud services. When you mix for example Google Drive and Google Cloud, you are combining two different systems so think hybrid.